# Python odeint- Initial condition y0 must be one-dimensional

Tags: python, odeint

I am trying to simulate a dynamic system in state space form with odeint.
My A matrix is 12*12 and B matrix is 12*4 (rows * cols) so my initial state vector is 12*1 as it suggests.

My code is as follows

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

tmp = np.loadtxt("system.txt", skiprows =2)

A=np.matrix(tmp)[0:12,0:12]
B=np.matrix(tmp)[0:12,12:]

control = np.matrix([[0.0],[0.0],[-0.6310],[0.0]])

def aircraft(state, t):
    return A*state + B*control

state0 = np.array([[6.809827628],[0.439572153],[0.0],[0.0],[0.0],[0.0],[0.0],[0.0],[0.0],[0.0],[0.0],[0.0]])
t = np.arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.1)

state = odeint(aircraft, state0, t)
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sim.py", line 17, in <module>
    state = odeint(aircraft, state0, t)
  File "/home/aluminium/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py", line 215, in odeint
    ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords)
ValueError: Initial condition y0 must be one-dimensional.
```

Only way I can think of defining state vector is as a column vector. 
Can you please let me know how to define a initial state vector to overcome this problem ?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Ive got the answer and thought of sharing it here with the hope that someone with the same problem in the future will benefit.

odeint seems to expect 1d array as an state variable to call the function and 1d array return from the function as well.

So I reshaped the variables accordingly. here is the code.

```
def aircraft(state, t):
    xdot= A*state.reshape(12,1) + B*control
    return np.squeeze(np.asarray(xdot))

state0 = np.array([6.809827628,0.439572153,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape your y0 initial condition vector before passing it into the odeint function:

```
y0_reshaped = y0.reshape(n,)
```

where n = number of elements in your y0 vector.